# Angular2: Why does 'else' not get executed in subscribe function?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, if-statement, subscribe

I'm trying to verify that the response email field matches the email to the user which is logged-in. When I navigate to an URL (detail/:id) which was set up by another user and doesn't belong to the currently logged-in user, Angular should display an error message.

So far so good. But in my case, the else function, to display the correct response does not get executed. Also `console.log(appointmentDetails);` doesn't give me any output.

I already tested the template view as I inverted the if-statement. So this would work.

**UPDATE**: The `appointmentDetails = [0];` makes me confused.

**Valid JSON response:**

```
{
  id: 241772331,
  firstName: "Justin",
  lastName: "Miller",
  email: "justin@miller.com", ...
}
```

**Error JSON response:**

```
{
  success: false,
  message: 'You are not authorized to edit this apoointment.'
}
```

**Template view:**

```
<div class="row show-hide-message" *ngIf="message">
  <div [ngClass]="messageClass">
    {{ message }}
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  {{ appointmentDetails.type }}
  {{ appointmentDetails.firstName }}
  {{ appointmentDetails.lastName }}
</div>
```

**AppointmentDetailComponent:**

```
export class AppointmentDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  username = '';
  email = '';
  message;
  messageClass;
  getData: any;
  appointmentDetails = [0];
  id: number;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
    });
    this.getData = this.getDataFunction;
    this.getData();
  }

  getDataFunction() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.username = profile.user.username; // Set username
      this.email = profile.user.email; // Set e-mail
      if (profile.user.email) {
        console.log(this.id);
        this.apiService
          .getAppointmentDetailsById(this.id, this.email)
          .subscribe(appointmentDetails => {
            if (!appointmentDetails.success) {
              this.messageClass = 'alert alert-danger'; // Set error bootstrap class
              this.message = appointmentDetails.message; // Set error message
            } else {
              console.log(appointmentDetails);
              this.appointmentDetails = appointmentDetails;
            }
          });
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Server API route:

```
const url = process.env.acuityUri + '/appointments/' + id;
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    if (json.email === user.email) {
      res.json(json);
    } else {
        res.json({
          success: false,
          message: 'You are not authorized to edit this apoointment.'
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: In think you have wrong response coming from getAppointmentDetailsById.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are just returning two different objects in the success and failure scenarios and not throwing any error. So you must do the check in the first block of `subscribe` itself. No need to have the `error` block. So look for the `property` as a condition

So, use

```
this.apiService
  .getAppointmentDetailsById(this.id, this.email)
  .subscribe(appointmentDetails => {
    if (!appointmentDetails.hasOwnProperty('success') {
      this.messageClass = 'alert alert-danger'; // Set error bootstrap class
      this.message = appointmentDetails.message; // Set error message
    } else {
      console.log(appointmentDetails);
      this.appointmentDetails = appointmentDetails;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way,

```
this.apiService
  .getAppointmentDetailsById(this.id, this.email)
  .subscribe(appointmentDetails => {
      console.log(appointmentDetails);
      this.appointmentDetails = appointmentDetails;
    }, (error) => {
      this.messageClass = 'alert alert-danger'; // Set error bootstrap class
      this.message = error.message;
  });
```

Comment: And here is the supporting documentation if you'd like to add for clarity: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html

Comment: Now I get: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'number[]'.

Comment: If your error response is conforming to what you have posted, you should not have got it. Please `console.log()` the error message

Comment: I updated my question. "console.log(appointmentDetails);" also gets executed twice now.

Comment: What I meant is put a `console.log` in the error scenario. and show us. like `(error) => { console.log(error);
      this.messageClass = 'alert alert-danger'; // Set error bootstrap class
      this.message = error.message;
  }`

Comment: Nothing gets logged (I'm calling /details/:id which was not set up by me). Have a look into my "Error JSON response".

Comment: What is this showing `console.log(appointmentDetails);` in the subscribe success block?

Comment: @dileepkumar Either my custom success response or the correct JSON data from API. So this works.

Comment: I did not understand the above comment. Sorry? Is the issue resolved? I wanted to know what it shows in the console.log in both the scenarios( both the blocks)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188519/discussion-between-dmnktoe-and-dileepkumar-jami).